# Getting "Could not read from remote repository" when trying to update local forked repo from original repo

Tags: git, github, fork, git-remote

I created a fork of a repository per the instructions here -- https://guides.github.com/activities/forking/ .  Then I cloned this to my local machine.  I would like to update my local repository with the files from the master branch of the original repo, but I can't seem to figure it out.  I tried

```
localhost:resilience-app davea$ git remote add upstream https://github.com/factn/resilience-app
localhost:resilience-app davea$ git pull upstream/master
fatal: 'upstream/master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Please make sure you have the correct access rights

What's the right syntax for updating my local repo with the latest files from the original repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to specify both the name of the remote repository and the branch, separate them with a space instead of a slash: `git pull upstream master`. But `master` is usually the default branch, so you can just try `git pull upstream`.

Comment: "git pull upstream master" proved the winner